# Wordpress nested sub-category archive page url

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get a url of the form `/category/child-category` to show the child-category archive page. When I navigate to `/child-category` directly it works as expected, but when I try to nest the url I get a `404`.

I've tried changing the permalink in category to have a base of `/%category%/` which allows for `/category/child-category` but then that sends the parent category archive page `/category` into an infinite redirect.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, I just tested this on one of my WordPress sites, and it works as expected. I added a new category, setting an existing category as it's "parent". When I hit myurl.com/category, I get the category archive page. And, when I hit myurl.com/category/new-child-category, I get the new-child-category archive page. Maybe it's something in your apache/nginx config?